# Bootstrap-datepicker and django 1.4

Tags: python, django, datepicker

I am a noob in coding, but I want to add [eternicode datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) to a project.

I will be using the date formats in different languages. If you go to [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) and select the language of Chinese (zh-CN) and select a date, the date that is returned to the input field is `2013年12月27日`.

My question is: should I be using a DateField or a TextField in my models.py and forms.py files. If I use a date field, will the date be returned as 2013-12-27 or 2013年12月27日 for the Chinese language? Do I have to add formatting to return the date as 2013年12月27日? if I use a TextField will this be easier to format the date field?

Additionally, is there an understandable tutorial for a noob to add the datepicker to a django 1.4 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should most definitely use a `DateField`. By using a `TextField`, you lose the built-in validation and any ability to do "date-based" queries (at least via the ORM).

The date and time formats used by Django are controlled by so-called "format files"; here are the [formats for zh_CN](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/zh_CN/formats.py) and for comparison [for de](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/de/formats.py). As you can see, there are no formats defined for zh_CN yet, but you can [write your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files) and maybe even write a patch to add zh_CN localization to Django.